# Angular2 Atfer Subscribe Event div is not updating

Tags: angular

i have a Problem:
in a view i want to redner an errormessage

//HTML

```
<div [(hidden)]="!errorMessage" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Error</strong> {{ errorMessage }}
</div>
```

//Component

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.authService.authenticated.subscribe(result => {
    if(result){
      this.navigateToHome();
    }
  });
  this.authService.authenticationError.subscribe(message => {
    this.errorMessage = message;
    this.showError(message);
    console.log(message);
  })
}
```

The Problem now : the errorMessage is only shown when i vire it a second time.
The Console shows everytime a message, but the div is only updating every second request.
The handler is always called !

I decoreated the property with :  @Output()public errorMessage:string;

but that doesnt seems to help

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` instead of `[(hidden)]` as below :

```
<div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Error</strong> {{ errorMessage }}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , even if im using ngIf it just working on the second request :(